# Spacemacs fails to load after installation on Arch Linux

Tags: spacemacs

I have been trying to use spacemacs on Antergos (Arch Derivative) but when I start emacs it doesn't load spacemacs. it used to work before just fine but not anymore. I'm also very new to emacs so I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: How are you starting Emacs, how did you install spacemacs, etc.

Comment: I've started Emacs both normally and in the terminal. I installed both Emacs and Spacemacs from the arch package repository using yaourt if that helps.

Comment: I'm confused, as I don't see spacemacs on the AUR website... Where is spacemacs actually installed on your system?

Comment: It was in the AUR website last night. It seems that they took the package down. This is not the first time it's been taken down. I believe spacemacs is installed in my home directory in the .emacs folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest first installing emacs using pacman:

`pacman -Sy emacs`

and then installing spacemacs using git:

`git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d`

OR your can use the develop version of spacemacs which is more current and will have more feataures:

`git clone -b develop https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d`

I'm not sure how yaourt installs spacemacs; I would use the suggested method of installing spacemacs as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is that I deleted the entire .emacs.d directory and deleted the .spacemacs file in my home directory since I was reinstalling spacemacs. For some odd reason the .spacemacs file wasn't letting Spacemacs reinstall. After that the process that @haff mentions works perfectly fine.

Comment: you can accept the answer by haff and put this answer as a comment to it.